# Error regarding Uploading an Image in mysql db using SpringBoot and thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-thymeleaf

I was trying to add a profile pic when setting up the profile page unfortunately, I couldn't. Here is what I did.

1: Added an image tag and an input of type file

code:

-- Here instead of name I added th:field="*{profilePic}" still this is not binding with the pojo field

2: Updated Address table with an new Column profilePic with type blob;

3: Added this filed in the Address Entity class and also in Profile Pojo class as Profile Pojo is a simple pojo class which has all the fields in Person and Address Entity. Given inorder to get the data from a form to edit my Profile details

code:    in Address entity class:

```
                    @Lob

                    @Column(name = "profilePic",nullable = true)

                     private byte[] profilePic;

         in Profile Pojo :

                     @Lob     

                      private byte[] profilePic;
```

4: Controller handling the request @{/updateProfile}" (above form)

code:   @RequestMapping(value = "/updateProfile")

I used the @RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile file bcoz I couldn't get the file from profile object passed into this req and cannot use byte()

```
 public String updateProfile(@RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile file, @Valid @ModelAttribute("editprofile") Profile profile, Errors errors,                                 HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
```

if(errors.hasErrors()){

return "EditProfile.html";

}

PersonPojo person=(PersonPojo) httpSession.getAttribute("loggedInPerson");         log.info(file.getOriginalFilename().toString());

```
     person.setName(profile.getName());
```

person.setEmail(profile.getEmail());

person.setMobileNumber(profile.getMobileNumber());

if(person.getAddress() == null || !(person.getAddress().getAddressId()>0)){

```
 person.setAddress(new AddressPoJO());

    }
```

person.getAddress().setAddress1(profile.getAddress1());         person.getAddress().setAddress2(profile.getAddress2());

person.getAddress().setCity(profile.getCity());

person.getAddress().setState(profile.getState());         person.getAddress().setZip_code(profile.getZipCode());        person.getAddress().setProfilePic(imageUtil.compressImage(file.getBytes()));       personRepository.save(person);

httpSession.setAttribute("loggedInPerson", person);

return "redirect:/displayProfile";

}

5: Error am getting is when saving the person to repository

in code :  personRepository.save(person);

the error is :

could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet // This is the error showing in the browser (via Global exception handler)

error in console:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'addresspoj1_.profile_pic' in 'field list'

and also pointing to the line of code personRepository.save(person);

Note: column name at db is profilePic and in the address and profile pojo its profilePic even its same I given name attr also.

I tried adding the name in the Address and profile pojo as profile_pic as in the error and given name attribute to the field in Address Pojo Entity class. Still not working

Comment: How does your PersonRepository looks like?
Have you looked in the DB if the column profile_pic in the Table addresspoj1_ really exists!?

Comment: And check this:
https://sebhastian.com/mysql-unknown-column-field-list/

Comment: Yes in my address table i added column profilePic with type blob

Comment: I renammed the column name in the address table as profile_pic now the error solved and new one arised

Comment: The code worked perfect and i added the image and other details into the db. But the problem is I can't load the image and other details into thymleaf. When I click my show profile its loading for some times then my lap got heated.